# Cassandra CQL not equal operator on any column

Tags: cassandra, cql

Hi is there any way I can use != operator using CQL in Cassandra?
I am trying to use a != operator on my columnfamily but when I try using that it says:

```
cqlsh:EPCContent> select * from "MediaCategoryGroup" where "MCategoryID"!=1;
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid syntax at line 1, char 55
  select * from "MediaCategoryGroup" where "MCategoryID"!=1;
                                                        ^
```

Answer (score 19):

If you look at the [Cassandra SELECT syntax](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#select), you will see that the `WHERE` clause must be "composed of relations on the columns that are part of the PRIMARY KEY and/or have a secondary index defined on them." Does your column conform to that specification?

Just for your information this is the full list of relation operators: `'=' | '<' | '>' | '<=' | '>=' | '!=' | IN | CONTAINS | CONTAINS KEY`.

Comment: But we can use "<" | ">" | "<=" | ">=" only if that field is a Primary key.

Comment: yes, in Cassandra you can only do that on primary key fields (also from composite keys) or "secondary indexes" and not all of them are possible all the times...

Comment: How would you do it to get all the rows where a specific field is not null?

Comment: @DavidTorres I am not sure you will be able to do that directly on a Cassandra query. As mentioned you cannot use the "!=" operator (not sure if this has changed on recent versions of Cassandra). Furthermore, I believe the fields you can use in filtering/operators (part of primary key or composite key) all need to be different from null... So, most probably you need to perform a read of relevant elements and then do some other filtering on your application.

Answer (score -3):

Go with <> instead !=. It's working for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).